# Difference between the requirement of a comparator in sort() and stable_sort()

Tags: c++

If I pass a lambda as a reference argument to sort algorithm it is working. But when I pass the same lambda to `stable_sort` it is not compiling and I have to declare the argument `const`? Why it is so?

```
// sort algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

using namespace std;

void print(std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myvector = { 32, 71, 12, 45, 26, 80, 53, 33 };

    sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](int &i, int &j)//working
    {
        return i < j;
    });

    stable_sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](int &i, int &j)//not compiling
    {
        return i < j;
    });

    stable_sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](const int &i, const int &j)//compiling
    {
        return i < j;
    });

    print(myvector);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `[](int i, int j) { return i < j; }` also (for `sort()` as well as `stable_sort()`)?

Comment: Yes i tried its working. But my doubt is why the same lambda not working on stable_sort  which did for sort when i pass the argument by reference.

Comment: *[Bug libstdc++/82891] stable_sort() won't compile with function object that takes parameters by non-const reference* - https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2017-11/msg00878.html

Comment: An what error message does your compiler give?

Answer (score 0):

> [[Bug libstdc++/82891] stable_sort() won't compile with function object that takes parameters by non-const reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2017-11/msg00878.html)
>
> There is now an LWG issue submission request waiting to become published for
>   this. I'll return when it has been added.

There are issues for both GCC and LLVM but they wait on a request<sup>[[3](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3031)]</sup> to the [Library Working Group](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/) to change the standard.